How to connect speakers to NAD 3020 amplifier?
The vintage NAD 3020 I have inherited uses bare copper wires for the speaker connection. The speakers I want to buy have RCA connectors but I'm struggeling to source the RCA to bare copper wire adapter.
What would be the easiest / best way to connect speakers that use bare copper wires?
These are the speakers I want to use.

We're not mind readers, so a link to the speakers you want to buy would help a lot. Also, is it the 70s 3020 or the 2000s model same name? Speaker connector to RCA isn't probably going to work, and whether it burns a fuse or something more important is up to luck.

@ojs Ok, speakers added.

https://www.avforums.com/ is good for this type of information.  However, what ojs and Tim say is correct.  These modern active speakers are not suitable for this antique amplifier.  Except as ojs says, if you use the pre-amp outputs but then you are skipping the main part of the amplifier.

@badjohn those old NAD amplifiers are intentionally designed to work as preamplifiers (I used to have a 7240PE that had the same feature). Is there something wrong with not using the power amp section?

@ojs Nothing wrong.  It's just a little sad to not use half a nice device.

Your speakers are active speakers, which means that they have built-in amplifier. They are intended to be used with a mixer or a computer audio interface, not a power amplifier. The RCA inputs are for line level input, that is much, much lower power than speaker level. Do not connect speaker outputs to the active speakers' input unless you are willing to break things and possibly start a fire.
The 70s 3020 and many other old NAD amplifiers however have separate pre- and power amplifier sections. If you want to use the amplifier with active speakers, you can remove the bridge between "pre amp out" and "normal in" connections in the back and use normal RCA cables to connect "pre amp out" to the speakers. Some reasons to do this could be using the vinyl preamp, input selection and volume control on the 3020.

DO NOT CONNECT WIRES AS YOU THINK.
The NAD has two pairs of bare wire outputs (L&R), to connect to PASSIVE speakers. That's because it's not just a mixer, for want of a better term, but an amplifier in its own right.
All it needs is a pair of PASSIVE speakers, with nothing but the speakers themselves inside The active ones you crave have their own speakers, BUT also their own amplifier. So connecting the ports as you think will result in amplifying an already amplified signal. Not good.
Small speakers, such as you need, will often have the same bare wire connectors on their backs. If not, phono/RCA sockets will be there instead. Very rarely will small studio speakers have XLR or Speakons, or even jacks. So any coded twin cables will suffice.
When connecting wires, check that the marked one goes to the same pos. or neg. at both ends. It won't hurt to get it wrong - you'll just lose a lot of bass reproduction.
And, while you're at it, download/print the user manual for the NAD - it will save asking all sorts of questions, and you'll learn better how it all works.
In actual answer to the question - but don't do it - is quite simply buy a pair of RCA to RCA cables, readily available, and cut off the plugs from one end! Surely that would give you what you thought you needed! What could have been more simple. But as luck would have it, that option wasn't taken..!

I have an old 3020 and its manual (the original paper one).  It doesn't say not to connect active speakers but only because they were not a common thing at the time.  However, I agree with everything you say: these speakers are not suitable for this amplifier.

You have chosen active speakers, with their own power amplifiers.   If you wish to connect them to the NAD 3020 use the 'pre amp out' or 'tape play' outputs.

You own one of the most respected stereo amplifiers of the late 1970's.
Kudos to you. It's a great piece of equipment!
Here's what you do;
Connect the RCA plugs to the speaker inputs.
Note which rubber-shielded wire goes to the red connector, and which one goes to the white one, for each speaker. There is very often a subtle stripe painted on one wire or the other. Keep in mind which is which.
Use a wire-stripper (best choice) or a sharp pocket knife to cut off the red and white leads on the other end of your wire sets.
Pull the paired wires apart, about an inch and a half down.
This is quite easy, and requires very little force.
Strip off 3/4 of an inch of the rubber insulation from each wire set.
Give the copper bare wire ends an even twist to keep the ends from splaying.
Ensure that the NAD 3020 is powered off for this next step.
Now, press up on the red plastic tab for the left channel output on the back of the NAD 3020, and insert the bare copper wire end into the aperture.
Release the red tab.
Repeat this process for the left channel black tab and associated wire end, and then for both tabs on the right channel output.
Power up your system, and enjoy the music!!
UPDATE: I just noticed the link in ojs's original query, detailing the nature of the speakers intended for use.
They are powered speakers.
The instructions I offered immediately above here were for unpowered speakers.
Please do not acquire those powered speakers if you wish to connect them to the NAD 3020.
There are plenty of unpowered speaker options out there, surely.

The NAD has 4 speaker inputs but the speakers has only one left and one right RCA port. Should I buy a 2-female-1-male RCA converter?

Are there any non-active speakers that have RCA inputs? I've seen only wire/banana terminals and 2-pin DIN.

@NeilMeyer RCA cables have two wires, positive and negative/ground. But you really shouldn't do this.

Most modern stand-alone PA speakers (powered and unpowered) have 1/4 inch speaker cable inputs and/or XLR inputs (microphone style jacks).
Smaller stereo component speakers and studio monitors generally have the RCA inputs, yes.

@Sparquelito you missed Speakon for PA speakers. And are there really passive speakers with RCA connectors?

ojs,
Yes. Many passive speakers come with RCA input jacks.
Mostly ones sold as a set with the complete stereo outfit.

@Sparquelito link, please. I'm sorry, I'd normally let this go but applying your advice here could do real damage.

I have found a nice pair of passive speakers can I connect them to the headphone jack with a speakon to jack converter?

@NeilMeyer those words don't make much sense together. Anyway, if you have a new question, please post a new question.

@Sparquelito - I've found that modern speakers - passive, use Speakon or 1/4 jacks. Powered - use canon (XLR).  But the speakers OP wants to use are hardly PA speakers - they're essentially studio monitors.
